# Hot Restart flutter app by one click of button

Tags: flutter, dart

I have developed a game. now When I click of a Elevated button.. I want my game to Restart. How  can I can do it in Flutter??

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() {
  runApp(const GameUI());
}

class GameUI extends StatefulWidget {
  const GameUI({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _GameUIState createState() => _GameUIState();
}

class _GameUIState extends State<GameUI> {
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Center(child: Text('Block Memory Game')),
        ),
        body: Stack(children: [

/*   Here is the whole game code 
 Here whole game is in the stack  And this last Align contains restart button */

          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: (){
                //what code to write here to restart the application
              },
                child:
                const Text('Restart Game')
            ),
          )
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
```

When we press hotRestart button the application starts the same thing I want it to happen when i click on `Restart Game` button

Answer (score -1):

Wrap your app with `StatefulWidget` then give it a key after that whenever you update the key app restarts as provided below in `restartGame()` function.
Also you can access this function from wherever with this line:

`Game.restartGame(context)`

```
class game extends State<Game> {
  Key key = UniqueKey();

  void restartGame() {
    setState(() {
      key = UniqueKey();
    });
  }
        
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return KeyedSubtree(
      key: key,
      child: Game(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Isn't underscoring a class name `class _game` a bad practice? This makes private class variables and methods but should not be used for a class. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Thankyou for the answer. Can you Clarify me the answer as I am not getting the app restarted it is just hot reloading. I want to change the values of the game on every restart. the code which you have provided is just allowing me to start the same game instance from first. help me with this as i am stuck here. and even `Game.restartGame(context)` is giving me error. If you need some data of game ill provide it.

Comment: @Tanguy Yes you are right, I was just setting a name.